# Convert R Date to POSIXct Date in Database

Tags: r, oracle, date, r-dbi

I want to use `dbGetQuery` to pull data from a database:

```
date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
string <- paste("select * from D where D_DATE >= '", date, "'", sep="")
D <- dbGetQuery(conn, string)
```

But the dates `D_DATE` in `D` have type `"POSIXct"`:
How can I fix my query?

Setting `date <- as.POSIXct(date)` didn't work

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: I connect R to an Oracle database

Comment: if your change your date to just date <- "2020-01-01" does it work? i do that on a firebird DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass date as string, then convert to date in SQL, something like:

```
date <- "2020-01-01"

string <- paste0("SELECT * FROM D WHERE D_DATE >= TO_DATE('", date, "', 'YYYY-MM-DD')")
string
# [1] "SELECT * FROM D WHERE D_DATE >= TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

We might need to truncate the *D_DATE*: `TRUNC(D_DATE)`